# Alexa-skills local test not working

Tags: node.js, express, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to host a skill locally.  I am using the alexa-skills npm module and the provided example code: https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-skills. I added in console.logs to check and see if code is being ran, when I run the script it listens but I get no console logs when I connect to it.

```
var express = require('express'),
    AlexaSkills = require('alexa-skills'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8000,
    alexa = new AlexaSkills({
        express: app, // required 
        route: "/", // optional, defaults to "/" 
        applicationId: "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.XXXXXXX" // optional, but recommended 
    });

alexa.launch(function(req, res) {

        console.log('launch \n');

    var phrase = "Welcome to my app!";
    var options = {
        shouldEndSession: false,
        outputSpeech: phrase,
        reprompt: "What was that?"
    };

    alexa.send(req, res, options);
});

alexa.intent('Hello', function(req, res, slots) {

    console.log('intent \n');
    console.log(slots);

    var phrase = 'Hello World!';
    var options = {
        shouldEndSession: true,
        outputSpeech: phrase,
        card: alexa.buildCard("Card Title", phrase)
    };

    alexa.send(req, res, options);
});

alexa.ended(function(req, res, reason) {
    console.log(reason);
});

console.log('starting server \n');
app.listen(port);
```

I use a curl command, to simulate what the echo would send (my echo isn't here yet):

```
curl -v -k http://localhost:8000/hello --data-binary '{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "SessionId.XXXXXXXXXX",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.echo-sdk-account.XXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "new": true
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "LaunchRequest",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId.XXXXXXXXX",
    "timestamp": "2016-01-18T05:36:27Z"
  }
}'
```

I get this response:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 493
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 493 out of 493 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 19
< Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:47:44 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
Cannot POST /hello
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

To me it looks like this is not working.  I don't see any attempt at a response being made from the code (when I test it I do make sure IDs match).  Why is this script not generating output and no log output?

```
Node = v5.4.1
npm = 3.3.12
express = 4.13.3
alexa-skills = 0.1.0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the curl request to http://localhost:8000/hello, but I believe it should be http://localhost:8000/.

When you attempt to use from Alexa, don't forget:

- to create a certificate (self-signed is sufficient for development)
- implement https if the node module doesn't do it for you (which could also be part of your problem if the module is doing it.
- use a named endpoint.  You can't use an IP address within the Alexa skill definition.  Use DuckDNS or simmilar service for a DNS entry.

Comment: Wow I am sorry, that's what I get for staying up late and working on it though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late to chime in, but this may make your life easier.

There is a tool that was built for local skill development.

[BST Tools](https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development)

Requests and responses from Alexa will be sent directly to your local server, so that you can quickly code and debug without having to do any deployments. I have found this to be very useful for our own development.

It's open source: https://github.com/bespoken/bst

Answer (score 0):

You can also test your skill locally by following this tutorial:
[How to test Alexa locally](https://medium.com/@moonahmad/how-to-test-alexa-locally-6d498e307a8)